# Credentials for the SQL Server Agent are invalid [2018]

Tags: sql-server, gateway, powerapps

I'm currently trying to build a small PowerApps application, mainly to mess around with it and learn what it can do. I have a gateway on my desktop that PowerApps has connected to, but whenever I try and create a connection I get the following error:
Credentials are missing or not valid. inner exception: The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid.

- SQL Server Name > DESKTOPNAME\PRAVDA
- SQL Database Name > Planner
- Authentication Type > Windows
- Username > DESKTOPNAME\MyWindowsUsername
- Password > My windows password
- Gateway > The correct gateway

I'm not sure why it's refusing to connect.

So far I have:

- Added SQL Server to my firewall exceptions
- Portforwarded ports 1433, 443, 5671-5672, and 9350-9354
- Googled the hell out of it

What now?

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: who is the agent running as?

Comment: @MitchWheat I've just realised that I'm using a version of SQL Management Studio that does not appear to have a SQL Server Agent! Stupid of me

Comment: sql agent is part of your sql server installation, not SSMS. SSMS is just a GUI. If you can't see the agent node, then you have insufficient permissions to view it.

Comment: @MitchWheat As you can guess I'm a beginner to doing this myself. I'm going to try installing SQL server again, and make sure it has the agent

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm not sure what the server agent is running as. I'm running it from an admin account, and the SQLAGENT$PLANNER login has sysadmin. Additionally, restarting it requires admin. Hope this is the information you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using SQL Server 2017 - Express Edition, which does not have the SQL Server Agent available. This was rectified by switching to Developer Edition, which was suitable for my purposes.